# Higher-order HKR theorems?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, derived-algebraic-geometry

Recall that [Hochschild-Kostant-Rosenberg -type theorems](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Hochschild-Kostant-Rosenberg+theorem) identify certain smoothness conditions guaranteeing an isomorphism between the [cotangent complex](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cotangent+complex) and (a shift of) the [Hochschild homology](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Hochschild+cohomology) of an algebra $A$.

The reason one might hope for something like this in the first place is the following. The cotangent complex is

$$L_A = \Sigma^\infty_{CAlg_{A//A}}(A \otimes A) = \varinjlim_n \Omega^n_{CAlg_{A//A}} \Sigma^n_{CAlg_{A//A}} (A \otimes A)$$

whereas the shifted Hochschild homology is

$$\Omega HH(A) = A \times_{A \otimes_{A \otimes A} A} A = \Omega_{CAlg_{A//A}} \Sigma_{CAlg_{A//A}} (A \otimes A)$$

So an HKR theorem says that the colimit $\varinjlim_n \Omega^n \Sigma^n$ stabilizes after one step, under certain smoothness conditions.

**Question 1:** Does this colimit ever stabilize after a finite number of steps which is greater than 1? If so, does this correspond to some kind of conditions on how singular $A$ is?

**Question 2:** Is this HKR phenomenon of $\Omega^n \Sigma^n$ stabilizing after one step in any way related to similar "group completion" phenomena in algebraic K-theory? For instance, I believe that the $S_\bullet$ construction generally only needs $\Omega B$ to be applied once before it stabilizes.

Comment: Via cofibrant replacement, applying the HKR theorem levelwise extends it to all simplicial rings, when expressed in terms of the cotangent complex.

Comment: The premise of the question confuses me - HKR identifies HH_*  with the symmetric algebra of the shifted cotangent complex (aka differential forms), not the shifted complex itself.. also no smoothness is necessary but characteristic zero is.